# Setting a variable to two decimal places in python 3 method definition

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment that I am writing in Python 3. We must define a class with a few methods and write the input to a binary. Now I have written the program and it is 99% correct. I am just having a problem with getting the values I enter to display to 2 decimal places. I have used the round function and the %.2f and it keeps displaying to 1 decimal place.

Here is the class I defined:

```py
import pickle

class Shoe:

    def __init__(self):
        self.style = ""
        self.price = 0.00

    def assignValues(self, style, price):
        self.style = style
        self.price = price

    def calcDiscountPrice(self, style):
        if self.style == "A" or self.style == "a":           
            self.priceD = price -(price / 10.00)
        elif self.style == "B" or self.style == "b":
            self.priceD = price - (price / 20.00)
        elif self.style == "O" or self.style == "o":
            self.priceD = price

    def dispValues(self):      
        print("Shoe style:",self.style)
        print("Price: R ", self.price)
        print("Discounted price is R",self.priceD)
        print('\n')
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `%.02f`?

Comment: i have tried that but it gives me a syntax error on the %

Comment: just so i am sure we are on the same page. I am trying to %.02f on the dispValues method

Comment: I don't understand (maybe because Python is not my primary language). Where do you use `%.2f`? Can you show the code? If the result of round is something like `42.10` then it is no surprised that it is displayed `42.1`. But if you format when printing, then you should have the correct result : `print("Price : %.2f" % 42.1000);` displays `42.10`.

Comment: i used the %.2f at the  print("Price: R%.2f " % self.price) line. it didnt work but i found the problem. i had a comma between the qoute mark and the % that gave a syntax error, when i removed it, my code works without any problems

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. 
In dispValues -> `print("Price: R %.2f" %self.price)`
I had a comma before the second % that kept giving me syntax error.
My program is working 100% now